# Kubernetes job pod completed successfully but one of the containers were not ready

Tags: kubernetes

I've got some strange looking behavior.

When a `job` is run, it completes successfully but one of the containers says it's not (or was not..) ready:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                 READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE       IP           NODE
default       **********-migration-22-20-16-29-11-2018-xnffp       1/2       Completed   0          11h       10.4.5.8     gke-******
```

job yaml:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: migration-${timestamp_hhmmssddmmyy}
  labels:
    jobType: database-migration
spec:
  backoffLimit: 0
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: "${appApiImage}"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command:
          - php
          - artisan
          - migrate
      - name: cloudsql-proxy
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
        command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
                  "-instances=${SQL_INSTANCE_NAME}=tcp:3306",
                  "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 2  # non-root user
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
        volumeMounts:
          - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
            mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
            readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
```

What may be the cause of this behavior? There is no readiness or liveness probes defined on the containers.

If I do a describe on the pod, the relevant info is:

```
...
Command:
  php
  artisan
  migrate
State:          Terminated
  Reason:       Completed
  Exit Code:    0
  Started:      Thu, 29 Nov 2018 22:20:18 +0000
  Finished:     Thu, 29 Nov 2018 22:20:19 +0000
Ready:          False
Restart Count:  0
Requests:
  cpu:  100m
...
```

Answer (score 6):

A Pod with a `Ready` status means it *"is able to serve requests and should be added to the load balancing pools of all matching Services"*, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-conditions

In your case, you don't want to serve requests, but simply to execute `php artisan migrate` once, and done. So you don't have to worry about this status, the important part is the `State: Terminated` with a `Reason: Completed` and a zero exit code: your command did whatever and then exited successfully.

If the result of the command is not what you expected, you'd have to investigate the logs from the container that ran this command with `kubectl logs your-pod -c app` (where `app` is the name of the container you defined), and/or you would expect the `php artisan migrate` command to NOT issue a zero exit code.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was using istio, and experienced the same issue, removing istio-sidecar from the job pod solves this problem.

my solution if using istio:

```
  spec:
    template:
      metadata:
        annotations:
          sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
```

Comment: see also bug here: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/11045 , and here: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6324

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. My company infrastructure adds a sidecar'ed log forwarder by default; similarly excluded it via metadata/annotations.